# Is there a generic way to activate led flash light on android 1.6

Tags: android, android-sdk-1.6

I am trying to implement a code that uses the camera LED (Flash). It is similar to the torch applications that are available on the market. 
I guess in android 2.1 and above this can be achieved by using FLASH_MODE_TORCH. Is there a generic way to do the same on **android 1.6**.

Comment: i'm the developer to Cool flashlight did you find any way of activate led in android 1.6?

Comment: Native code!!! but had no idea how to use it. Its supposed to work.